# Why does adding and subtracting 2 months to a date not give back the same date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I'm a bit confused about this outcome, taking today's date minus 2 months, and then taking that date again and adding two months, does not give me today's date when assign the dates to a variable.

> Time.zone
>   "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"

```
> today = Date.today.in_time_zone
=> Thu, 31 Aug 2017 00:00:00 EDT -04:00

> a = today - 2.months # This is persisted to the db
=> Fri, 30 Jun 2017 00:00:00 EDT -04:00

> b = a + 2.months
=> Wed, 30 Aug 2017 00:00:00 EDT -04:00
```

If I however, just use the same object, it moves back and forth properly:

```
> today = Date.today.in_time_zone
=> Thu, 31 Aug 2017 00:00:00 EDT -04:00

> today - 2.months
=> Fri, 30 Jun 2017 00:00:00 EDT -04:00

> today + 2.months
=> Tue, 31 Oct 2017 00:00:00 EDT -04:00
```

The problem is obviously when "a" gets saved to a database, and then retrieved later on, and calculated plus 2 months..., it should match today's date.

Comment: have you tried `(today - 2.months) + 2.months` (parenthesis not needed, but just to demonstrate) ?

Comment: the problem with adding a "month" is that all the months are not the same duration, there is some interpretation that the date/time framework must do...  Often, when you add or substract months, you want to land on the the same day number of the next / previous months. But if it's not possible, then the day number must change.

Comment: > (today - 2.months) + 2.months
 => Wed, 30 Aug 2017 00:00:00 EDT -04:00

Comment: And, I hope it is obvious for you now, the issue has nothing to do with assigning values to a variable. It is just that you actually didn't tried the same operations in your two groups of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

**A month is not a fixed duration**. Adding or taking a month does not give the same "time shift" depending on which day you are.

## The usual algorithm

to add or take months is the following :

- **try to land on the same day number** (4th, 30th, 31st) as you started, just by changing the month
- if you would land on an impossible date (like 31th September, 30th February, 29th February for *some* years) then **just go the maximum allowed day number** of this month

*This implies that adding some months then taking out the same number of months will not necessarily give you back the same date.*

### Examples :

31st of some month + 1 month --> One would want to get to the 31th of next month

But if there is no 31st of next month (like for 31th of August, no 31st of September), then what to do ?

Usual interpretation would say that you want to go to the end of the month, this is 30th September (for rent or other monthly subscription, for instance)

---

But usually, 30th of some month - 1 month --> One would want to get to the 30th of the previous month.

That would lead to .... 30th of August. Not 31th of August.

**Hence: some date + 1 month - 1 month does not necessarily give the original date !**

---

### **Another example** :

Start at the 30th of August.

Take a month -> 30th of July

Add a month -> You want to get to 30th of August (same number, next month) or to the end of August ?

The default algorithm will try to give the same day number -> 30th of August (which is more logical now)

---

### Also with days...

Note that the same problem happens with days,but much less often ! When some days don't have the same number of hours, for daylight saving days, when adding and taking same number of days you might not get back to the original *date and time* as you started from.

Comment: But it seems that there is something missing/odd in this framework here, in my opinion, shouldn't this framework be smart enough given August 31st 2017 what 2 months ago should be?, is it Date - (31 days x 2) or is it subtract days until you reach a new month, and then subtract days until you reach the 2nd new month? The same going up? I just think there is something amiss here?

Comment: This is an inherent problem, there *must* be an error, whatever solution you choose. A month is **not** a fixed duration, and the framework can't "know" that you actually want to get back to some precise start date. Correct DateTime system computation  in programming is a **very hard** problem to handle.

Comment: I think, as I say in my answer, that the thing all the framework, AFAIK, try to do is : when you add 1 month to August, you must land somewhere in  September. If you were to add 31 days to August, you would land in 1st of October, so this is bad, so it will take you back a day before, to 30th of September.

Comment: The algorithm in general is : try to get the **same day number** to another month. If the day number is too large, just take the largest day number of this month instead.

Comment: The algorithm must be general and predictable. Also, think that it cannot know what calculations you did before getting to this particular date. I hope I gave enough examples to convince you. But all this is the reason for some specific frameworks to exist, don't hesitate to search for one that calculates these things as you need it.

Comment: Thank you Pac0, yeah, I might need to write something custom for this, I need more predictability for my specific application. Thanks for all the time!